# Ruby on Rails: How do I set a variable to a constant, where part of the name of the constant can change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to do

`current_user.field = User::????????`?

Where `??????????` would be whatever I wanted it to be

This what I'm trying to do

```
Given /^"([^\"]*)" is a(?:|n) "([^\"]*)"$/ do |arg1, arg2|
  cur_user = User.find(:first, :conditions => ['name = ?', arg1])
  cur_user.update_attributes(:role => User::arg2.constantize)
end
```

While constantize does't work for this use, I do know that it would work In Object.var.constantize context

Comment: constant can change? then what is the meaning of constant?please explain in detail what you need give some example or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use:

```
"User::#{arg2}".constantize
```

or

```
User.const_get(arg2)
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem you're trying to solve?  Using constants this way is a code smell, you should probably be using something like ActiveHash if you've got a set of Enumeration values or something that's configuration to walk through.

If you do need to solve your problem this way, check out const_defined?() and const_get() for this.  const_get() will allow you to do a dynamic value call on a symbol/string constant name without constantizing it.

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001689

Comment: Smells good to me. I think the problem he is trying to solve is well illustrated too (if you know cucumber).

Comment: Hey Marc, that example was added later.  Given this example, something like ActiveHash feels like a better way to define the set of Roles than constant Role IDs: http://github.com/zilkey/active_hash

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
????????.constantize
```

you can do any thing

Comment: Almost, I found a typo in my post. I meant User:: not User.

While, what you have will work in most cases, it does't for mine T_T