# Using a Variable Name as Attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to DRY up my Rails code by making a common method that will be reused.  In order to do so, I have to make some field/attributes and the class name that is used in the code variables, so it can work for the three models (and their fields) with the same code.  I tried to learn from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913860/how-to-use-a-variable-as-object-attribute-in-rails) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256171/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-a-constant-where-part-of-the-name-of), but I haven't been able to get it to work.

In my model, I have this:

```
def self.update_percentages    
  update_percentages_2(User, "rank", "top_percent")   
end   

def self.update_percentages_2(klass, rank_field, percent_field)
  rank_class = (klass.name).constantize
  total_ranks = rank_class.maximum(rank_field)
  top_5 = (total_ranks * 0.05).ceil 

  rank_class.find_each do |f|
    if f.send("#{rank_field}") <= top_5
      f.send("#{percent_field}", 5)
      f.save
    end
  end 
end
```

With this code, I get `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`.  When I start commenting lines out to narrow down the problem, it seems that the `f.send("#{percent_field}", 5)` causes the error.

And if I add: 
`percent_field = (percent_field).constantize`

I get: `Name Error: wrong constant name top_percent`.

Can someone please help me determine what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to assign to an attribute, you need the method name with the equal sign:

```
f.send("#{percent_field}=", 5)
```

Also, this:

```
rank_class = (klass.name).constantize
```

is equivalent to this:

```
rank_class = klass
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite your method to update all qualifying records in on transaction.

```
def self.update_percentages_2(klass, rank_field, percent_field)
  top_5 = ( klass.maximum(rank_field) * 0.05).ceil   
  klass.where("#{rank_field} <= ?", top_5).update_all(percent_field => 5)
end
```

**BTW**

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913860/how-to-use-a-variable-as-object-attribute-in-rails/3913887#3913887) to your original question.